# $H^2$-regularity of a solution to a Poisson equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, regularity-theory-of-pdes, poissons-equation, elliptic-equations

Let

- $d\in\mathbb N$
- $\Lambda\subseteq\mathbb R^d$ be bounded and open
- $f\in L^2(\Lambda)$
- $p\in L_{\text{loc}}^2(\Lambda)$ admit a weak gradient $\nabla p\in L^2(\Lambda,\mathbb R^d)$

> Assuming $$\Delta p=f\;,\tag 1$$ i.e. $$\langle\nabla\phi,\nabla p\rangle_{L^2(\Lambda,\:\mathbb R^d)}=-\langle\phi,f\rangle_{L^2(\Lambda)}\;\;\;\text{for all }\phi\in C_c^\infty(\Lambda)\;,\tag 2$$ are we able to conclude $p\in H^2(\Lambda)$?

I know that this true under some regularity assumptions on $\partial\Lambda$. Since I'm particularly interested in a cube, the only regularity of $\partial\Lambda$ I'm willing to assume is being Lipschitz.

Comment: I think you need to specify some boundary conditions in order to get a global estimate.

Comment: @Jose27 Is a Lipschitz boundary sufficient?

Comment: I meant boundary conditions on $p $, not restrictions on the domain ( although these play a role too).

Comment: @Jose27 It would be fine for me, if we assume Dirichlet boundary conditions, $p\in H_0^1(\Lambda)$. Can we conclude $p\in H^2(\Lambda)$ with that assumption, for the general $\Lambda$ of the question?

Answer (score 4):

$H^2$-regularity of $p$ is valid if $\Lambda$ is a bounded, polyhedral set,
see chapter 4 of Grisvard's book "Elliptic problems in nonsmooth domains".

Comment: I guess you've got Theorem 4.3.1.4 in mind. However, it's only stated for a polygon in $\mathbb R^2$. Is there a similar result for polyhedra in higher dimensions (in particular, in $\mathbb R^3$)?

Comment: What about section 8.1? On p. 371, it is stated "This shows again the regularity of $u$ in $H^2(\Omega)$ when $\Omega$ is a convex polyhedron."

Comment: It's rather vague, isn't it?

Comment: Maybe. I havn't read the preceding theorems.

Comment: Sorry for replying to this old post, but can we show that if $f\in H^k(\Lambda)$, then for $p\in H_0^1(\Lambda)$ satisfying $(2)$ it holds $p\in H^{k+1}(\Lambda)$?

Comment: No, you need additional boundary regularity for this. In two dimensions, the maximum regularity depends on the maximal interior angle of your domain (keyword "corner singularity").

Comment: Thank you for your comment. The claim is trivial when $d=1$ though, right? In general, is it enough to assume that $\Lambda$ is an embedded $C^l$-submanifold without boundary (for $l=1$ or do we need $l=\infty$)?

Comment: Yes, in $d = 1$ this is trivial, since open intervals are regular enough. However $\Lambda$ will always have a boundary? And the regularity of $\Lambda$ will depend on the requested regularity on $u$, i.e., maybe something like $l \ge k-1$ (this inequality is only a **very** wild guess).